# How to save image name in database in the form of current date and time

Tags: c#, image, datetime

I want to save image in the database with name current date and time. For Eg. If am going to upload an image named as waterfall.jpg then it should be saved as 20142801020000PM.jpg. 
Following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;

namespace GalleryAnd_Album
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRAVIN-LENOVO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gallery;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FU1.HasFile)
            {
                int album_company_id=1;
                string album_addedonstatus="y";
                string album_addedby="0";
                string str=FU1.FileName;

                string a = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmtt") + ".jpg";
                FU1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".")+ "//Album//"+a);
                string path = "~//Album//" + a.ToString();
                FU1.SaveAs(path);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Album values ('" + txttitle.Text + "','" + txtdescription.Text + "','" + path + "','" + album_company_id + "','" + album_addedby + "','" + album_addedonstatus + "')", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                lblmessage.Text="Image uploaded succesfully";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                con.Close();               
            }
        }      

        protected void lbview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("view_album.aspx");
        }

    }
}
```

And my error is:

The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path'~//Album//2014-01-28 1406PM.jpg' is not rooted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide absolute file path when calling `SaveAs`:

```
FU1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your problems could be resolved with

```
a = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmtt") + ".jpg";
string rootedPath = Server.MapPath("~//Album//" + a.ToString());
FU1.PostedFile.SaveAs(rootedPath);
```

and remove the second (redundant) SaveAs

But then you should take your attention to your sql command string. It is a big security risk full open to Sql Injection

```
con.Open();
string cmdText = "Insert into Album values (@title, @desc, @path, @aid, @aby, @stat";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title",txttitle.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc",txtdescription.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", rootedPath);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aid",album_company_id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aby",album_addedby );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat",album_addedonstatus );
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```